# Skip error while bulk inserting

Tags: sql, mysql

I am using following query to bulk insert from one table to another.

```
INSERT INTO billitems SELECT * FROM billitems_old;
```

I want that if insert fails on any row, it must skip that row and proceed. Is there anything that I can include in the above query to skip errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert ignore into billitems select * from billitems_old;
```

reference: [insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)

Comment: what kind of errors? can't you be be more specific? (perhaps update your question with this info)

Comment: Foreign key error that it was originally showing. It is stopping on errors, when I want it to skip it.

Comment: Come on, can't you just, like, copy&paste the error here? My crystal ball of magically writing correct SQL doesn't seem to work today.

Comment: Here is the error: "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`stockist`.`billitems`, CONSTRAINT `FK_billitems_1` FOREIGN KEY (`BillNo`, `BillDate`) REFERENCES `billdetails` (`BillNo`, `BillDate`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)"

Comment: Well, as far as I know, this can be circumvented by setting `foreign_key_checks` to 0 before the insert. Re-enable it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

From the online [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html):

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors
>   that occur while executing the INSERT
>   statement are treated as warnings
>   instead.

So try:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO billitems SELECT * FROM billitems_old
```